# Django model with manytomany field, not getting saved. Is data population designed properly?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

I think I'm not properly populating the data, for a model that has a manytomany field.  I wanted to create a model with the days of the week, so that people can select any days that they want to receive mail notifications.  The resulting generated html, looks correct.  I.e. I can select the checkboxes days, But when I click the submit bottom, only all the other fields get properly saved in the database, not the days of the week selection.  I'm sure I'm making a very simple mistake, regarding how the data model.  But I can't see it. Should the following work?  Here's my model for the days of the week:

```
DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
('1', 'Monday'),
('2', 'Tuesday'),
('3', 'Wednesday'),
('4', 'Thursday'),
('5', 'Friday'),
('6', 'Saturday'),
('7', 'Sunday'),
)

class Days(models.Model):
    days = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK)
```

The part of the mail notification model that references the days:

```
class Preferences(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    mail_days = models.ManyToManyField(Days)
```

The part of the form where the days are selected, is here:

```
DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
    ('1', 'Monday'),
    ('2', 'Tuesday'),
    ('3', 'Wednesday'),
    ('4', 'Thursday'),
    ('5', 'Friday'),
    ('6', 'Saturday'),
    ('7', 'Sunday'),
    )

mail_days = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
            widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK)
```

The form displays correctly, i.e. checkboxes for the days of the week appear.  When I select the boxes, and hit submit, everything looks ok.   But if I select the form again , the checkboxes are all empty. The other fields of the form that I changed, get saved properly.

I think perhaps I see a problem.  Here's the SQL database table, that gets created for the days model.  It's empty.  It's not populated with anything.  Shouldn't it be?

```
CREATE TABLE `myapp_days` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `days` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `todo_days` WRITE;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The selected days are getting saved into a table called myapp_preferences_my_days:

```
CREATE TABLE `myapp_preferences_mail_days` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `preferences_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `days_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `preferences_id` (`preferences_id`,`days_id`),
  KEY `myapp_preferences_mail_days_2d9474d5` (`preferences_id`),
  KEY `myapp_preferences_mail_days_96c2dc77` (`days_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `myapp_preferences_mail_days` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `myapp_preferences_mail_days` VALUES (15,1,6),(14,1,4),(13,1,5);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Any insights to my problem?  Many thanks.

Comment: Show us view that shows and saves the form.

Comment: This is the code. It's very simple.  Someone on the google django forum says that I should be using fixtures to populate the Days model, with the days of the week, and that using "choices", won't do that.  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>     form = EditPrefForm(request.POST,instance=p)
if request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your preference have been updated.")
    else:
        form = EditPrefForm(instance=p)

    return render(request,'todo/view_preferences.html', locals())